# Unit tests project with multiple application and databases - Circular dependency in TEST[DEPENDENCIES]

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

So I've got a django project with several applications.

Each application use its own database, and they share a common database containing django tables (such as auth, sessions).

For this I've got several database routers, so my settings looks like this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
     ..
    },
    'app1_db': {
      ..
    },
    'app2_db':{
    ..
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["site.db_router.App1Router", "site.db_router.App2Router"]
# no router for default database
```

Each application also got its unit tests. To troubleshoot my problem I extracted one of the application. It contains a tests module with four test files. Test file number one looks like below:

```
class ExcelTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    databases = ["app1_db"]
    # some tests
```

## Test case 1

`python manage.py test app1.tests.testfile1`  raises this error  `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Circular dependency in TEST[DEPENDENCIES]`

## Test case 2

I comment the databases section : only default test database is created (not the application one) and this error is raised:

```
AssertionError: Database queries to 'app1_db' are not allowed in this test. Add 'app1_db' to app1.tests.testfile1.ExcelTestCase.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this fai
lure.
```

## Test case 3

I uncomment `databases` setting and run `python manage.py test app1.tests` so every test are runned.

Three test files out of four are `TransactionTestCase` and therefore have `databases` settings.

I need to comment at least the first or third (second one is not TransactionTestCase) test file databases or I get Circulary dependency error, and by doing so I got `AssertionError` because I can't use the app database.

I'm using Django 2.2 and have been struggling on this issue for a while, any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe setting your 'DEPENDECIES'.

[controlling creation order for test databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/#controlling-creation-order-for-test-databases)

Check that they receive a list of dependencies and the databases without dependencies receive an EMPTY list.

Basically you have to add something like:

```
'default': {
 ..
    'TEST': {
        'DEPENDENCIES': ['app1_db'],
    },
},
'app1_db': {
# ... db settings
    'TEST': {
        'DEPENDENCIES': [],
    },
}
```

Comment: Indeed setting dependencies solved the issue, in addition I had to specify `databases = {'app1_db', 'default'}` in the test Class. Thanks !